# One word for things which are different for different people, or exclusive to the person to which they belong?

Tags: vocabulary

What is an English words which describes that something is different for different people, or in other words, it's kind of exclusive to the person they belong to.

For example I want to say that *there is nothing like "the-best-sleeping-duration". Sleep requirements vary with people. Different people have different sleep requirements.*

Likewise, I want to say that *there is nothing like the best method to study. Different methods are best-suited for different people.* It's kind of *subjective*.

Comment: Hi Solace - Please note that "kinda" is not a recognised abbreviation in English. You might see it on informal websites, in representations of spoken dialog or in cartoons but definitely not in grammatical written English.

Comment: Uh, "personal"?

Comment: @HotLicks -  Huh?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Thank you. This is a useful piece of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with [personal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/personal) based on your example.

> 1 :  of, relating to, or affecting a particular person

While subjective is a synonym for personal, it has a connotation that you can control it. I wouldn't say your requirement for sleep is something you can change as easily as your opinion on a matter. [Antonyms for subjective](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/subjective) include objective, unbiased, and unemotional. [Antonyms for personal](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/personal) include common, public, and general.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may mean **subjective**.

> subjective
>
> /səbˈdʒɛktɪv/
>
> adjective
>
> 1. based on or influenced by personal feelings, tastes, or opinions. "his
>      views are highly subjective"
>
> synonyms: personal, personalized, individual, internal, emotional,
>   instinctive, intuitive, impressionistic;
>
> [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=subjective%20definition)

Answer (score 0):

there can be a distinction between the denotative meaning of a word and its connotative meaning. in some cases the different understanding between people can be associated with differences in the connotations of a word

Answer (score 0):

The word is **connotation**. It's the emotional "baggage" a word carries with different people based on their individual experience with said word.